# CSV import looping duplicate times

Tags: python, csv

Rather new to the Python world. I wrote the following script to convert my csv file and overwrite the existing JSON file, ready to upload to Firebase. Problem is, the script is reading each row 4 times which is odd. My code is below, would be great to know where I'm going wrong.

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

fieldnames = ("Code", "Currency", "Rate", "Last Updated")
entries = []

with open('rates.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        entry = OrderedDict()
        for field in fieldnames:
            entry[field] = row[field]
            entries.append(entry)

output = {
    "rates": entries
    }

with open('rates2.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(output, jsonfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Example of the CSV
[CSV IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVYFG.png)

Example Output

```
{
  "rates": [
    {
      "Code": "﻿AED ",
      "Currency": " UAE Dirham",
      "Rate": "4.2499",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "﻿AED ",
      "Currency": " UAE Dirham",
      "Rate": "4.2499",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "﻿AED ",
      "Currency": " UAE Dirham",
      "Rate": "4.2499",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "﻿AED ",
      "Currency": " UAE Dirham",
      "Rate": "4.2499",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "AUD ",
      "Currency": " Australian Dollar",
      "Rate": "1.8299",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "AUD ",
      "Currency": " Australian Dollar",
      "Rate": "1.8299",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "AUD ",
      "Currency": " Australian Dollar",
      "Rate": "1.8299",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    },
    {
      "Code": "AUD ",
      "Currency": " Australian Dollar",
      "Rate": "1.8299",
      "Last Updated": "18/02/2020 10:13"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `entries.append(entry)` should no be inside the inner loop. You are appending to it for every field, rather than for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just un-indent `entries.append(...)`:

```
with open('rates.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        entry = OrderedDict()
        for field in fieldnames:
            entry[field] = row[field]
        entries.append(entry)
```

otherwise you are appending a new row for every field, when you in fact only want to do this once per row, not once per field.

Comment: Thank you! Coming from a JS background I had no idea the indentation affected the scope.

Comment: The other thing that was happening here, but is fixed in this answer, is that you were adding 4 references to the same `OrderedDict` object which is why you got the full duplication each time instead of `col1`, and then `col, col2`, `col1, col2, col3` etc because each time you appended to `entries` you were updating all the references as well.